# Grouping data from different pandas dataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have different pandas DataFrame in the form of:

dataFrame 1:

```
NY_resitor1 NY_resitor2 SF_resistor1 SF_resitor2 NJ_resitor1 NJ_resistor2
     45           36          36          40         20            56
     47           36          35          34         25            59
      .            .           .           .          .             .
     49           39          32          39         22            59
```

dataFrame 2:

```
NY_voltage1 NY_voltage2 SF_voltage1 SF_voltage2 NJ_voltage1 NJ_voltager2   CHI_voltage1     
     45           36          36          40         20            56         45    

     47           36          35          34         25            59

      .            .           .           .          .             .
     49           39          32          39         22            59
```

I would like to group my frames based on first letters(letters before _) of the dataframe column names.  In this example i would like to have four DataFrames with column names as follows:.

DataFrame1:

```
NY_resitor1 NY_resitor2 NY_voltage1 NY_voltage2
```

DataFrame2:

```
SF_resitor1 SF_resitor2 SF_voltage1 SF_voltage2
```

DataFrame3:

```
NJ_resitor1 NJ_resitor2 NJ_voltage1 NJ_voltage2
```

and 
DataFrame4:

```
CHI_voltage1
```

How can I do it in an efficient way?

Comment: have you got the expected answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group create a column `MultiIndex` as explained below.

```
array = [7215,7217,7344, 3434, 4343, 43]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(array, (len(array), 1)),columns=['NY_resitor1', 'NY_resitor2', 'SF_resistor1', 'SF_resitor2', 'NJ_resitor1', 'NJ_resistor2'])
array = [7215,7217,7344, 3434, 4343, 43, 34]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(array, (len(array), 1)),columns=['NY_voltage1', 'NY_voltage2', 'SF_voltage1', 'SF_voltage2', 'NJ_voltage1', 'NJ_voltager2','CHI_voltage1'])

# Merging the two DataFrame
df = df1.join(df2)

# Creating a Multiindex for columns
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
# We have just to get the group from the column MultiIndex
df_group = 'NY'
data_frame_1 = df.loc[:,df_group].rename(columns = lambda x : df_group + '_' + x)
print(data_frame_1)

   NY_resitor1  NY_resitor2  NY_voltage1  NY_voltage2
0         7215         7217         7215         7217
1         7215         7217         7215         7217
2         7215         7217         7215         7217
3         7215         7217         7215         7217
4         7215         7217         7215         7217
5         7215         7217         7215         7217
```

And so on for the other groups. Here is a screenshot of the `DataFrame` with the `MultiIndex`.
[image]

You can also iterate through groups.

```
for df_group in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    sub_df = df.loc[:,df_group].rename(columns = lambda x : df_group + '_' + x)
    print(sub_df)

   NY_resitor1  NY_resitor2  NY_voltage1  NY_voltage2
0         7215         7217         7215         7217
1         7215         7217         7215         7217
2         7215         7217         7215         7217
...
   SF_resistor1  SF_resitor2  SF_voltage1  SF_voltage2
0          7344         3434         7344         3434
1          7344         3434         7344         3434
2          7344         3434         7344         3434
...
```

Comment: Thank you Romain, but the problem is that, i dont always know the columns name in advance; so is there a way to do that dynamically?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to do it dynamically.

Comment: it works ok for this example; but could you please explain what does that lambda do? What happen if we had more concatenated name on the column names and we wanted to select based on a string from the 2 positon lile SF_Resitor1_Max and we wanted to group based on MAX?

Comment: The `lambda` is here to recompose the column name i.e. add the prefix and the `_` to the name of the column. Without this operation, the column name would appear as in the screenshot. If another value is added after a `_` (MAX for e.g.), the `split` will create a `MultiIndex` with 3 levels instead of 2 (the table displayed in the screenshot will have 3 levels of columns). Then it will be possible to use this level, but it will require some code modification according to the expectations.